# How to load CSS module with next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use the `react-datepicker`module in my react App, but I'm having a hard time trying to load the css module of react-datepicker. I'm using next.js to render my app on server side.

I tried to implement a css loader provided by next to solve this kind of issue, but I got an error trying to build my app: 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kue4d.png)

My component.js file:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';
```

My nex.config.js file:

```
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withImages(
    withCSS({
        cssModules: true
    })
);
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my imports or config ? Or what the 'minimize' property (displayed on the error message) means ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: I ended up by importing css directly from  
`<link href="/static/react-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />`. [Original post](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/299)

Answer (score 0):

Your css modules must end with `.module.css`.

> To use CSS Modules, import a CSS file named *.module.css from any component. <sup>[src](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/global-styles)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Import this way instead:

```
import styles from 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-min.module.css'
```

Answer (score -1):

## Try using Compose in your config file

I think you need to compose your plugins like so

```
// ... other imports
const compose = require('next-compose');

module.exports = compose([
  withImages(),
  withCss(),
  {
    webpack: (config) => {
      /**some special code */
      return config
    }
  }
]);
```

Details about the plugin can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-compose)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the same error message trying your config

Comment: `next-compose` is only effectively syntactic sugar, ridding the code of long chains of `withPluginA(withPluginB(withPluginC(....)))`

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine!
Instead of importing CSS into a component, try to import it into the page you wanted to use it on.

Next.js supports only custom page CSS imports.